Extrusion effect on SVG
I am trying to create an extrusion effect with a shadow on existing svg files.
My approach is to have the unaltered file on one hand and use it as a source to another file on the other hand, in which I hope the effect can be achieved with just a mask/filter.
Doing it this way should allow me to reuse this effect on many svg files, apply another effect if needed and/or combine effects without altering the source files.
example.svg (source):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 5 5" stroke-width="2">
<path stroke="#000" d="m0,1h5"/>
<path stroke="#444" d="m0,2h5"/>
<path stroke="#888" d="m0,3h5"/>
<path stroke="#CCC" d="m0,4h5"/>
<path stroke="#FFF" d="m0,5h5"/>
</svg>

extruded.svg (container with the extrusion effect):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id="extrusion">
<!-- Mask definition to be replaced -->
<rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="white" />
</mask>
<image href="example.svg" mask="url(#extrusion)"/>
</svg>

For reference, this is a side-by-side illustration of the original file and the effect I am trying to achieve (extrusion + shadow).

Is it possible?

Looks like the filter effect I did on the Flagmeister SVG flags (can't link to one flag with the filter directly, as all flags are created dynamically as Data-UIT-img)

Here is a decoded SVG: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/xpqcz192/

Something like this?


<svg width="200px" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='80 0 480 480'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id='clip'>
      <path fill='#000' id='none' d='m430 31a122 122 0 0 0-111 69 122 122 0 0 0-233 52c0 128 233 297 233 297s233-169 233-297a122 122 0 0 0-122-122' transform='' />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <filter id='ff'>
    <feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='4' result='f'></feGaussianBlur>
    <feOffset dy='4' dx='4'></feOffset>
    <feComposite in2='f' operator='arithmetic' k2='-1' k3='1' result='a'></feComposite>
    <feFlood flood-color='#ddd'></feFlood>
    <feComposite in2='a' operator='in'></feComposite>
    <feComposite in2='SourceGraphic' result='b' operator='over'></feComposite>
    <feGaussianBlur in='b' stdDeviation='4'></feGaussianBlur>
    <feOffset dy='-8' dx='-8'></feOffset>
    <feComposite in2='b' operator='arithmetic' k2='-1' k3='1' result='c'></feComposite>
    <feFlood flood-color='#333'></feFlood>
    <feComposite in2='c' operator='in'></feComposite>
    <feComposite in2='b' operator='over' result='d'></feComposite>
    <feSpecularLighting result='e' in='d' specularExponent='15' lighting-color='transparent'>
      <fePointLight x='320' y='240' z='70' />
    </feSpecularLighting>
    <feComposite in2='e' in='d' operator='arithmetic' k1='0' k2='1' k3='1' k4='0' />
  </filter>
  <g filter='url(#ff)'>
    <g clip-path='url(#clip)' transform=''>
      <path fill='#e70000' id='none' d='M0 0h640v80H0' transform='' />
      <path fill='#ff8c00' id='none' d='M0 80h640v80H0' transform='' />
      <path fill='#ffef00' id='none' d='M0 160h640v80H0' transform='' />
      <path fill='#00811f' id='none' d='M0 240h640v80H0' transform='' />
      <path fill='#0044ff' id='none' d='M0 320h640v80H0' transform='' />
      <path fill='#760089' id='none' d='M0 400h640v80H0' transform='' />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>



note: Its the output from https://flagmeister.github.io

Not a perfect replica of the image (sides, especially the top and left borders, are quite different with a visible diagonal line to mark the orientation of the "3d" effect) -> do you have a way to do it?

Sorry, I did this years ago, copy the code and update your question, plenty of filter gurus around here, maybe a new question attracts more readers

That's a good solution nonetheless thanks
